# Regex to find same consonants anywhere in a word, not just consecutively

Tags: python, regex

What is a regex which finds how many words in a text corpus have the same consonant appearing more than four times?
As an example, the German word Sonnentrunkenheiten has 6 n.

This regex `([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])\1{3,}` shows me only the four consecutive consonants.

Comment: What language/tool are you using, or what flavour of regex? Please [edit] to add the tag(s). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool for counting the number of words; you'd just use the regex to match a word and add that to the total. But maybe you just phrased that poorly.

Comment: The example word has 6 ns, but not consecutively.  Your regex doesn't allow vowels *between* the consonants.  I agree regex is a poor choice for solution. 
 It sounds like you should remove the vowels, sort the string's remaining characters, then you can regex like you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python anyway, you really don't need a regex for this. But here,

```
r'([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])(\w*?\1){3,}'
```

A better solution would use `Counter` and print all the consonants which occur more than three times (so both "n" and "k" from "kankeudenkaankohan")

Comment: I suspect this is an excercise in using regular expressions. `Counter()` solves the problem but doesn't achieve the academic goal.

Comment: Google Translate erroneously guesses that my example word is Afrikaans. Try "kotikäynninkinkö" instead (though the translation isn't entirely accurate, it loses one of the suffixes).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a term to allow matching other parts of the word, in a group with `\1`. I'll use `.*` here for convenience. And I'll make it a non-capturing group since there's no need to capture the last occurrence.

```
([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])(?:.*\1){3,}
```

[Try it online on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UchnBO/3)

Example matches:

```
Sonnentrunkenheiten
assess
```

Also matches (due to `.*` instead of something more precise):

```
Acca Dacca
```

Comment: `.*` will allow it to match between different words. Use `[a-z]*` to keep it in the same word.

Comment: @Barmar Whoops, I didn't realize regex101 automatically enables multiline (and global). I turned them off.

Comment: What does multline have to do with it? That just affects the interpretation of `^` and `$`. I was talking about text with multiple words separated by spaces.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I misunderstood what you're saying, and I thought MULTILINE implied DOTALL. OP's talking about a text corpus so I assume they're only matching one word at a time, or maybe a file with one word per line, so there would never be a problem with `.*` matching whitespace.

Comment: @Barmar Plus I confused the word "corpus" with "lexicon"! Whoops, lemme edit.

Comment: I interpreted "text corpus" as somsthing like the complete works of Shakespeare, not a simple word list.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, you're right. Like I said, I confused "corpus" with "lexicon". But IDK what OP would consider part of a word (e.g. hyphen, apostrophe, underscore), so I'm leaving it up to them.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... What is a regex which finds how many words in a text corpus have the same consonant appearing more than four times? ..."*

Well, to match a word, you would use the following.

```
([^aeiouy])(?:.*?\1){3}
```

Although, I recommend just using a *for-loop* to parse the values.

Here is an example for a single word.

```py
import re
s = 'Sonnentrunkenheiten'
v = 'aeiouy'
m = {x: 0 for x in set(s) if x not in v}
for c in s:
    if c not in v:
        m[c] += 1
```

Output

```
{'t': 2, 'r': 1, 'h': 1, 'S': 1, 'n': 6, 'k': 1}
```

And, here is an example for a sentence.

```py
s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
v = 'aeiouy'
for w in s.split():
    m = {x: 0 for x in set(w) if x not in v}
    for c in w:
        if c not in v:
            m[c] += 1
    print(f"'{w}'")
    print(m)
```

Output

```
'Lorem'
{'r': 1, 'L': 1, 'm': 1}
'ipsum'
{'s': 1, 'p': 1, 'm': 1}
'dolor'
{'d': 1, 'r': 1, 'l': 1}
'sit'
{'t': 1, 's': 1}
'amet'
{'t': 1, 'm': 1}
```

From here, just write a *method* to return the count.

```py
v = 'aeiouy'
def f(s):
    z = 0
    for w in s.split():
        m = {x: 0 for x in set(w) if x not in v}
        for c in w:
            if c not in v: m[c] += 1
        if sorted(m.values())[-1] >= 4: z += 1
    return z
```

Answer (score 0):

negate sonants in re.findall, and compute the length of the result list

```
s = "Sonnentrunkenheiten"

def f(st, char = 'n'):
    return len([x for x in re.findall(r'[^aeiouy]',s) if x == char])

print(f(s))

6
```